# XSLT 1.0 Move of one Segment

Tags: xslt-1.0

please tell me, how can i move the Segment "BGM" from "CNT" to "GRP"?

Actually XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEEDELFOR>
 <AG/>
 <CNT>
  <TRANSMISSION_DATE>20190307</TRANSMISSION_DATE>
  <TRANSMISSION_TIME>113300</TRANSMISSION_TIME>      </INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER>
  </SENDER>
  </SENDER_QUALIFIER>
  </RECEIVER>
  </RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>
  </SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>
  </SYNTAX_VERSION>
  <BGM>227</BGM>
  <GRP>   
   </IDENTIFIER_BY>
   </IDENTIFIER_SU>
   </DATE_4>
   </REF_ON>       
  </GRP>
 </CNT>
</SEEDELFOR>
```

Correct output of my XML Should be:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEEDELFOR>
 <AG/>
 <CNT>
  <TRANSMISSION_DATE>20190307</TRANSMISSION_DATE>
  <TRANSMISSION_TIME>113300</TRANSMISSION_TIME>
  <SENDER></SENDER>
  </SENDER_QUALIFIER>
  </RECEIVER>
  </RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>
  </SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>
  </SYNTAX_VERSION>  
  <GRP>
      <BGM>227</BGM>             
  </GRP>
 </CNT>
</SEEDELFOR>
```

Here´s my XSLT: I tried to copy, but i think it´s better to move the segment?

Edit: Thats my full XSLT: Maybe i have to cominate with other copy segments?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
<!--Copy all of CNT != BGM-->    
<xsl:template match="CNT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()!='BGM']" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--copy BGM from CNT to GRP-->
<xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:element name="GRP">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:copy-of select="../BGM" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!--copy the data from ADD/CONTACT with Qualifier EM to GRP, so it can be used in the mapping to set EMAIL from Customer-->
<xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select ="./ADD/CONTACT">
         <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='EM'">          
  <CONTACT_EMAIL>
  <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>      
  </CONTACT_EMAIL>
       </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='TE'">          
  <CONTACT_TEL>
  <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>      
  </CONTACT_TEL>
       </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='FX'">          
  <CONTACT_FAX>
  <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>      
  </CONTACT_FAX>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!--delete IC node-->
  <xsl:template match="IC" />
  
  <!--delete FILTER_SET node-->
  <xsl:template match="FILTER_SET" />
 
  <!--delete SEE_AG node-->
  <xsl:template match="SEE_AG" />

  <!--delete ME node-->
  <xsl:template match="ME" />
  
    <!--delete ADD node-->
  <xsl:template match="ADD" />
  
  <!-- delete segment (ADD) with specified QUALIFER (SU)  -->
  <xsl:template match="ADD[QUALIFIER='SU']"/> 
  
  <!--delete TRANSPORT_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="TRANSPORT_DETAILS" />
  
  <!--delete PACKAGE_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="PACKAGE_DETAILS" />
  
  <!--delete AMOUNT_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="AMOUNT_DETAILS" />
  
    <!--delete IC node-->
  <xsl:template match="CONTACT" />
  
   <!-- delete empty nodes -->
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
<!-- delete empty nodes -->  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for your help.

Best regards
Julian

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: yes, i dont need the segment BGM at CNT, i need this at GRP. so i have to move with xslt.

Comment: I meant, do you have a specific problem with your XSLT? If so, show us where you're stuck so we can help you fix it. Otherwise you're just asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: i edit with my xslt. i tried to copy but it didn´t work. and i think (if possible) its better to move from CNT to GRP because i don´t neet at CNT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic approach to "moving" a node from one place to another is:

- copy everything as is,
- except the node in question, and
- copy the node to its new place:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove BGM -->
<xsl:template match="BGM"/>

<xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <!-- add BGM -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="../BGM" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you need to modify other nodes, add templates matching them as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your XML is not well formed. If I have got it right then you can find below xslt to achieve your requirement:

XML can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEEDELFOR>
<AG />
<CNT>
    <TRANSMISSION_DATE>20190307</TRANSMISSION_DATE>
    <TRANSMISSION_TIME>113300</TRANSMISSION_TIME>
    <INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER />
    <SENDER />
    <SENDER_QUALIFIER />
    <RECEIVER />
    <RECEIVER_QUALIFIER />
    <SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER />
    <SYNTAX_VERSION />
    <BGM>227</BGM>
    <GRP>
        <IDENTIFIER_BY />
        <IDENTIFIER_SU />
        <DATE_4 />
        <REF_ON />
    </GRP>
</CNT>
</SEEDELFOR>
```

An the solution would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CNT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()!='BGM']" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:element name="GRP">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:copy-of select="../BGM" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/eieE3Q5

Comment: hi, thanks. it won´t work at my case. i added my full xslt please helpt me

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- remove BGM at CNT-->
<xsl:template match="BGM"/>

<!--copy the data from ADD/CONTACT with Qualifier EM to GRP, so it can be used in the mapping to set EMAIL from Customer-->
<xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select ="./ADD/CONTACT">
         <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='EM'">          
  <CONTACT_EMAIL>
  <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>      
  </CONTACT_EMAIL>
       </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='TE'">          
  <CONTACT_TEL>
  <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>      
  </CONTACT_TEL>
       </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='FX'">          
  <CONTACT_FAX>
  <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>      
  </CONTACT_FAX>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    <!--copy BGM from CNT to GRP -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="../BGM" />
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```